# ROW TO COLUMN - Split and Stuff

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, split

I have this code

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX), @vals AS NVARCHAR(MAX), @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX) 

SELECT @cols = STUFF(( SELECT ',' + x.Name
                    FROM (
                    SELECT Name FROM Persons)x
                    FOR xml PATH(''), TYPE
                    ).value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)')
                    ,1,1,'') 

SELECT @vals = STUFF((SELECT ','+y.Column
                    FROM (
                    SELECT CONVERT (varchar, x.Subject) Column FROM subjects x) y
                    FOR XML PATH (''), TYPE).value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'')
SELECT @vals


SET @query = 'SELECT d.id, d.val Column, e.val Value 
              FROM (SELECT * FROM dbo.Split('''+@cols+''','','')) d, 
              (SELECT * FROM dbo.Split('''+@vals+''', '','')) e
              WHERE d.id = e.id'
```

That convert to a separate string with commas (WITH STUFF), and then pass it to a column(val) defined by a split function. Convert all the Names into a string separated by commas [Paco, Juan, Pepe, Maria] and returns it to column BUT 
I want that a row of a table to be separated by commas [Paco, Perez, Ingles] [Juan, Hernandez, Historia], to later pass it to a column. Something like that:

```
|ID |  Name | LastName |  Subject  |         |ID | Col   |   Col   |
| - | ----- | -------- | --------- |         | - | ----- | ------- |
| 1 |  Paco |   Perez  |  English  |  ------>| 1 |  Paco |   Juan  |
| 2 | Juan  | Hernandez|  History  |  ------>| 2 | Perez |Hernandez|
| 3 | Pepe  |   Salas  |   Spanish |         | 3 |English|vHistory | 
| 4 | MAria |   Cruz   |    Arts   |
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Nice job posting details for your question. Why would you need to do this to your data? This looks you would need a dynamic UNPIVOT. I have never tried something like that as it just sounds awful. You will run into the max number of columns doing this if you have more than 1,000 rows.

Comment: Thanks. Sounds awful and it's awful haha. Yes, I have more than 1000 rows, as you say, I will use UNPIVOT.